# c# use a generic function to pass parameter to a function with many overloads

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I am trying to create the following function:

```
    public static byte[] ValueToBigEndian<T>(T data)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        // We want to use big endian
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data).Reverse().ToArray();
            //bytes.Take(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(data)); // probabl don't need this
        }
        else
        {
            // Host is big endian already
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data;
            //bytes.Take(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(data)); // probabl don't need this
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

So here I am using `BitConverter.GetBytes(...)` which is not generic, but it has many overloads (`ushort`, `int`, `bool`, `ulong`, `long`, `short`, etc...).

I am trying to avoid writing matching overloaded functions for each of these, so my idea was to use a generic function. IMHO this would run fine until someone tries to use a type that is not in the overload list, and then the compiler would complain. But the compiler immediately complains since there is no overload for type `T`.

The error I get is

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'bool'

Is there a way to achieve what I am attempting here?

Comment: You can´t do this, the compiler needs to know what `T` can be in order to resolve a call to `GetBytes`. As `T` can be of any types (from the signature), also `object` or any other types is possible whereas there is no such overload for `GetBytes`. So I guess what you want to do is not possible and you´re stuck on using the overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic would state that this could be done. However, there is no common type (other than `Object`) that all value types inherit from that any overload of `BitConverter.GetBytes` would accept as a parameter.

One thing you could do instead is to instead use a generic parameter and just trust that the value passed into the method is one of the valid parameter types for `BitConverter.GetBytes`:

```
public static byte[] ValueToBigEndian(dynamic data)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes);

    return bytes;
}
```

I'd prefer this method over using Reflection, as it's easier to understand what is going on and I believe it would also run faster (untested claim). However, like Reflection, you would have to do your own type checking to catch occasions when an object of an incompatible type is passed. (This can be handled by a try-catch, but I'm not sure if that would necessarily be considered "best practice".)

Comment: That works really well, simple and easy : ) - not sure if there is any issue with it, I have not tried to pass an object yet (hopefully get a compiler error), will update when I try this.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get this is because value types can't be templated. Personally, I think this is C# fail and will always cause duplication, despite what developers says about it.

All you can do, is create overload for each value type...

**Update**

Another, more dirty way, is to hack this out with reflection. You can actualy get method you need by doing this:

```
    public static byte[] GetBytesTemplated<T>(T value) where T : struct
    {
        var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("GetBytes", new[]{typeof(T)});
        return (byte[])method.Invoke(null, new object[]{value});
    }
```

But, this way you need to check your template for value type yourself.
Your final code will look something like this:

```
public static byte[] ValueToBigEndian<T>(T data) where T : struct
{
    byte[] bytes = GetBytesTemplated(data);
    // We want to use big endian
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Putting a constraint `where T : struct` in combination with reflection might be the best way to go - since all overloads of `GetBytes` take a type which is a value type. The constraint at least provide a *bit* of compile time protection.